# Character encoding - copy/paste from web

Tags: utf-8, python-3.x, ansi

This is more an educational question about character encoding (hobbyist coder here) - but I have encountered this specific problem:

1) I wrote a silly program in python 3, in the editor I am using ALWAYS UTF-8 (german keyboard here).

2) To share my "creation" with interested family-members... I pasted the code into a private Pastebin.com (with instructions: copy/paste (raw) file into text-file and change file extension to .py)

Here the trouble starts:

3) Following these instructions will not allow to run the program.

4) I am not sure why it doesn't work, but since the character-encoding is now ANSI I know this is the problem. Changing the encoding back to UTF-8 in a code-editor solves the problem.

The questions are:

a) Why does it change to ANSI?

b) Why doesn't it work anyway in ANSI (since just by eye the whole code looks the same)

c) How to conserve the UTF-8 encoding? I mean: my family doesn't know how to change the encoding... (I know... just send them the executable file. But as I said... educational)

edit: clarified python-3.x version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When they copy paste the text to editor and press save, that's where the trouble starts. When saving, you must specify encoding, or be at the mercy of some default like "ANSI". A text file cannot be saved without using some kind of encoding.

It might not work because you have declared `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` in your file, the text editor saving the file in "ANSI" has no knowledge of this and leave it as is of course. So the parser will try to read the file as UTF-8 and fail because it's not UTF-8.

You could just use `\uxxxx` escapes for non-ASCII characters in the source.

So instead of:

```
str = u"€"
```

Do

```
str = u"\u20AC"
```

Comment: Bizarre: no I didn't declare `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` , but now I tried it of course and contrary to your assumption... now it works. So - thank you! But I will take your suggestion with escapes for non-ASCII chars in consideration in future projects - seems a very robust way to me.

Comment: @Chrugel well that's weird. Are you not using `u`-strings? You are using python 2 right?

Comment: Uh - now I am really embarrassed by my ignorance: No, in this case it's just `"..."`, I didn't realize I should use `u`-strings. And it's python 3 (is there a difference regarding strings?). Anyway: My little problem is solved and I am sorry for any confusion.

Comment: @Chrugel ah I have assumed python 2 in my post. In python 3, the `coding` is unnecessary because it defaults to UTF-8 even without it. And `u` strings are also unnecessary in python 3 because normal strings in python3 are like what u strings are in python 2.